# If correctly installed, should I see an entry for the DVD drive in fstab, and if not should I add one manually?

Tags: dvd, fstab

I am having IO errors when using eject/eject-t commands and can not load media into the drive (discussed in another post).   I was expecting some reference to the DVD drive in fstab - I do not see one.

Is fstab populated automatically based on devices found during boot ?

If a device is not there, does it make any sense to add it manually?

Note that my drive is working during boot (i.e. I installed from the drive) once Ubuntu takes over from the BIOS thing go awry.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason to place an optical drive into your `fstab` file. I have no entries in my `fstab` file, and my optical drives can be used to play a movie, play an audio CD, burn a CD or DVD and view a DATA CD or DVD, plus ubuntu doesn't mount the Drive unless you insert a disc in.